# How to change the opacity value of textbox control

Tags: javascript, html

*Is it possible to change the opacity value of text in a textbox?*
If not, we have any other options. This is for user Login Form.

Comment: @Maddy here is my html code <asp:TextBox ForeColor ="#B2B2B2"  Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="false" text="PassWord"  CssClass  ="form-control input-lg" ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="283px"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the color in `rgba`

For example:-

```
color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
```

In the `255,0,0` is `RGB` value and last one `0.3` is opacity.

if you use this

```
input{    
    opacity : .1;
}
```

This will make whole `input` box transparent.

Comment: Thanks Maddy....Color is working.And I have another doubt.... What is the event for textbox onfocus event in javascript....

Comment: your answer is in your question that is onfocus="focusFunction()" event.

Comment: Message shows. Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'onfocus' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code, you change opacity of text box.

```
input{    
    opacity : .1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS try setting the color as rgba(), the a is the value of the opacity.

```
textarea {
  color: rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
}
```